# Typeset a solidus operator (free variable substitution)

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I would like to typeset an operator like the one used to specify substitutions of variables with values in computer science. This is a sketch, just keep in mind that all this should span about on a single line, not two:

```
v /
 / x

v1, v_2 /
       / x1, x2
```

Obviously a simple `v/x` does not solve my problem, since `v` and `x` are written on the same exact line while I would like to have them smaller, with the `v` part aligned to the top of the `/` and the `x` aligned to the bottom.

Can you help me solving my problem please?

Comment: Can you point to an actual printed version of this notation? If simple `v/x` doesn't work, but the expression has to occupy a single line what would that look like?

Comment: Could you explain what is wrong with `$v/x$`?

Comment: @AlanMunn, Seamus: Werner already answered my question, thanks you however. I wanted v and x printed on a slightly different heights.

Comment: I fixed my question in order to clarify this a little bit.

Comment: @Riccardo The symbol is called a [solidus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solidus)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: thanks for pointing it out, I improved the title of the question by including its name.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems like you might be after so-called "vulgar fractions". One such package that provides this is [`xfrac`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xfrac) by means of `\sfrac{<num>}{<denom>}`. A similar functionality is provided by [`nicefrac`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nicefrac) that supplies an analogous `\nicefrac{<num>}{<denom>}`. With package options one is also able to choose between "ugly" and "nice" (default) fractions. And finally there's [`faktor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/faktor) that produces similar-style fractions using `\faktor{<num>}{<denom>}` (it requires the [`amssymb` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb) though). Here are some comparisons:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfrac}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xfrac
\usepackage{nicefrac}% http://ctan.org/pkg/nicefrac
\usepackage{faktor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/faktor
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lmodern
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
  \verb!\xfrac! & $\sfrac{\mathbf{v}}{x}$ & $\sfrac{\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2}{x_1,x_2}$ \\
  \verb!\nicefrac! & $\nicefrac{\mathbf{v}}{x}$ & $\nicefrac{\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2}{x_1,x_2}$ \\
  \verb!\faktor! & $\faktor{\mathbf{v}}{x}$ & $\faktor{\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2}{x_1,x_2}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The choice of [`lmodern`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lmodern) was because of minor font substitutions when it comes to typesetting the denominator & numerator. It is also possible to write a macro that would typeset these respective entries differently, if needed. My choice of `\mathbf{...}` for the numerator was just a style choice.

Comment: Vulgar fractions... it's really difficult to search for the right packages when you don't know the correct keywords. This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much :)

Comment: @Werner Have a look at [Algebra and coalgebra in computer science](http://books.google.com.qa/books?id=ID6utXCIfUUC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=substitute+symbol+with+number+operator+computer+science&source=bl&ots=nJWh5bboeb&sig=AoBSMO041J020tUIwf1LWE2RHLk&hl=en&ei=ECCsTtqEN9HRrQfOp5XZDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=substitution&f=false), I am not sure that the correct symbol is used this way.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Either way, this may be personal preference. I am not familiar with fundamental computer science symbols and representations.

Comment: @Werner I am also not very familiar, especially with the new computer science, in my time it would have been := which we used generally as the assignment variable.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Well, nowadays we still use := sometimes if we want to define things. The syntax I'm referring to has a different meaning. Suppose you have a formula `P` in some calculus, where some free variables appear. You write `{v/x}P` or `[v/x]` (you can see both, depending on the conventions chosen by the authors) to mean the formula resulting from substituting every free occurrence of `x` in `P` with `v`.