# How to create A/B with LaTeX/LyX?

Tags: lyx, fractions, xfrac

I want to create `frac` with this style:

[image: ab]

Is this possible? I try to find another way, alternative to `xfrac`.

Comment: Related or duplicates: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41179/define-my-own-xfrac-command/  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33046/typeset-a-solidus-operator-free-variable-substitution/33047#33047

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the package `nicefrac`to achieve this:

```
$\nicefrac{A}{B}$
```

creates this output:

[image]